# Prove $det\frac{dS^t}{dx} = 1+ (\nabla f)*t + 0(t^2)$ where t is evaluated at zero for $\dot{x}=f(x,t)$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing, determinant, trace

This is essentially trying to prove Liouville's theorem holding for time-dependent systems. Where S is the action coming from the Hamiltonian system.

$\det\frac{dS^t}{dx} = 1+ (\nabla f)*t + 0(t^2)$ where t is evaluated at zero for $\dot{x}=f(x,t)$

I have proven $1+\operatorname{tr}(A)*t+0(t^2)$ which I'm assuming is the key part to this proof.

Where I was heading with this is after I have proven $1+\operatorname{tr}(A)*t+0(t^2)$ is, I could say the time-dependent system is being evaluated at $t=0$ so then the $\operatorname{tr}(A)$ is just that $(\nabla f)$ part.

Comment: What is $S^t$ defined as? Is it the action, and is the motion here coming from a Hamiltonian? Please add details to make the question self-contained, and explicitely state which of Liouville's theorems you are trying to prove.

Comment: @AlexR. Yes you are correct, it is the action